# Oracle: How do I add users to the HTTP ACL in Oracle 11?

Tags: oracle, index, oracle-11g-r2, monitoring

How do I add a user to the network ACL (access control list)?

When running this code

```
declare
    req utl_http.req;
begin
    req := utl_http.begin_request('http://example.com');
end;
```

I receive this error.

```
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
```

Comment: You should note that this is relevant for oracle 11 and changed for Oracle 12

Comment: @kevinsky, done. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, see if you have an ACL for port 80, the HTTP port.  If you do, it should look something like  this.

```
select * from dba_network_acls;

HOST     LOWER_PORT UPPER_PORT ACL                     ACLID                                                                                                                                                                                                
---      ---------- ---------- ---                     -----
*        80         80         /sys/acls/www.xml       1FBEC09C32D78F5AE05335D6488A7883
```

If you need to recreate it, you can drop it with this command:

```
dbms_network_acl_admin.drop_acl('www.xml');
```

Create the ACL:

```
 dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl(
     acl => 'www.xml',
     description => 'WWW ACL',
     principal => 'SCOTT',
     is_grant => true,
     privilege => 'connect'
 );
```

Assign hosts and ports to the ACL:

```
 dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl(
     acl => 'www.xml',
     host => '*',
     lower_port => 80
 );
```

Add users to the ACL:

```
 dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege(
     acl => 'www.xml',
     principal => 'OE',
     is_grant => true,
     privilege => 'connect'
 );
```

> *version note:* [kevinsky](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2453/kevinsky) points out that this is applicable for Oracle 11 but that it has changed in Oracle 12.